# Creating a cached object model for database application in java

Tags: java, database, caching, interface, generic-list

I have an application with a database and a structure as follows:

1. Abstract **DbObject** class which can be saved/updated/deleted in my database. This DbObject has an abstract method "dataChanged", which is called when the object is (asynchronously) saved/updated/deleted in the database. For example the "*OrderItem*" object which extends the DbObject:

   ```
   @Override
   public void dataChanged(int changedHow) {
       switch (changedHow) {
           case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_INSERT: {
               List<OrderItem> list = cache().getOrderItems();
               if (!list.contains(this)) {
                   list.add(this);
               }
               break;
           }
           case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_UPDATE: {
               break;
           }
           case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_DELETE: {
               List<OrderItem> list = cache().getOrderItems();
               if (list.contains(this)) {
                   list.remove(this);
               }
               break;
           }
       }
       CacheManager.cache().notifyListeners(changedHow, this,CacheManager.cache().getOrderItemListeners());
   }
   ```
2. Interface **CacheChangedListener**:

   ```
   public interface CacheChangedListener<T extends DbObject> {
       void onInserted(T object);
       void onUpdated(T object);
       void onDeleted(T object);
       void onCacheCleared();
   }
   ```
3. Singleton **CacheManager** which contains a lot of List< DbObject > variables and for each of these lists another List< CacheChangedListener< T >. The method "notifyListeners" is called from the DbObject:

   ```
   public <T extends DbObject> void notifyListeners(int changedHow, T object, List<CacheChangedListener<T>> listeners) {
       for (CacheChangedListener<T> l : listeners) {
           switch (changedHow) {
               case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_INSERT:
                   try {
                       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> l.onInserted(object));
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       LOG.error("Error after insert of " + object.getName(), e);
                   }
                   break;
               case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_UPDATE:
                   try {
                       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> l.onUpdated(object));
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       LOG.error("Error after update of " + object.getName(), e);
                   }
                   break;
               case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_DELETE:
                   try {
                       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> l.onDeleted(object));
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       LOG.error("Error after delete of " + object.getName(), e);
                   }
                   break;
               case DatabaseAccess.OBJECT_CACHE_CLEAR:
                   try {
                       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(l::onCacheCleared);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       LOG.error("Error after clearing cache", e);
                   }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

In my application there if for example a dialog which implements the CacheChangedListener< OrderItem > interface, this interface is added in the CacheManager list List< CacheChangedListener< OrderItem > > onOrderItemsChangedList. When an OrderItem is saved, the "dataChanged" method will be called -> this will call the cache().notifyListeners(...) method -> the dialog implementing the interface will be notified an OrderItem is saved.

My CacheManager contains a lot of Lists with DbObjects and as many Lists containing the Interfaces for the objects. For each listener list I have add and delete methods, ex:

```
public void addOnOrderItemsChangedListener(CacheChangedListener<OrderItem> cacheChangedListener) {
        if (!onOrderItemsChangedListenerList.contains(cacheChangedListener)) {
            onOrderItemsChangedListenerList.add(cacheChangedListener);
        }
    }

public void removeOnOrderItemsChangedListener(CacheChangedListener<OrderItem> cacheChangedListener) {
        if (onOrderItemsChangedListenerList.contains(cacheChangedListener)) {
            onOrderItemsChangedListenerList.remove(cacheChangedListener);
        }
    }
```

My question is: can I do this in a more generic way? It would be nice if I could have only one list or map with all the listeners. This way I would only need one addCacheListener and removeCacheListener method.

I could just make a List< CacheChangedListener > but I am stuck at retrieving the correct listener when a specific DbObject is changed..